# MS Access SELECT DISTINCT WHERE query as combobox row source

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to simplify a bit of code I've been working on in a MS Access 2010 database I've inherited. I want the user to enter a date in a form in a field [txtSelectDate], and then select from a combobox any [ProductName] for which a record is in the [uploads] table on the user's selected date.

Currently I have a special query designed to do that, but I was brushing up on my SQL and I wondered if I could do it completely within an SQL expression in the Property Sheet> Data > Row Source field.

My attempt was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Uploads].[ProductName] 
FROM Uploads 
WHERE [Uploads].[ImportDate] = [Forms]![Review]![txtSelectDate] 
ORDER BY [ProductName];
```

Which feels to me like it should work, but it gives me a blank combo with no options in it. If I take away the WHERE, I get options, but I get every option, regardless of if the [ProductName] value in question was actually in the Uploads on the date selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refresh your form after the date is entered- assuming they're on the same form, add an after update event to your text box:

```
Private Sub txtSelectDate_AfterUpdate()
    Me.refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: That was what stumped me generally last week. I have a refresh and requery subroutine on all my user-input form controls.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your txtSelectDate is correctly cast to Date type (or at least matches Uploads.ImportDate, whatever type it may be) or your query would return zero rows?

Comment: I'm certain that this part is already correct. txtSelectDate already drives two queries in the form that successfully filter out all records except those with a matching value in Uploads!ImportDate